# NPM doesn't show me latest version of json-parse-better-errors

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I'm trying to run the `npx create-react-app` on my local machine, but the script keeps failing when it's trying to install `json-parse-better-errors`. It's trying to find version 1.0.2, which according to https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-parse-better-errors, is the latest published version of the package.

However, when running `npm show json-parse-better-errors versions`, I only get `[ '1.0.0', '1.0.1' ]`.

What am I missing that I need to run in order for npm to allow me to install 1.0.2?

Answer (score 2):

You need to update your npm: `npm update`

Comment: Yeah, my `npm` comes from Debian `testing` and updating `7.5.2 => 7.4.0` did the trick ))